# jQuery/ javascript after something has been clicked, then check for something else

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a jquery plugin called mmenu to load a side menu when a button has been clicked. 
That works fine, but Im also trying to get a hamburger style image going at the same time. I start off with the three lines and then when the menu button pressed it changes into a cross, this seems to work.

my issue comes when trying to close the menu, I want it to return back to a cross. The mmenu allows you to click anywhere to close the menu but I cant get the jquery right to change it back. 
I added a class when the button (.menuvate) is clicked, called "active" which displays the cross but no matter how I try I cant get it to check that the class is active when anywhere on the page is clicked after the menu has been opened.

This is my code so far

```
$('.menuvate').click(function(){

    $("#my-menu").trigger("open.mm");
    $("#mm-0").addClass("menu-opened");
    $("#nav-toggle").addClass("active");
});

$(document).click(function() {
    alert("me");
});
```

I just put an alert in to tell me when this is being fired which of course it does everytime the page is clicked. 
How do I get it to check for the active class after the menu has been opened when the page is clicked again so I can remove the class and change it back?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to listen on the custom events to know if the menu is closing or closed.

Basically, what you want is:

```
$("#my-menu")
     .on( "closing.mm", function() {
        alert( "The menu has started closing." );
     })
     .on( "closed.mm", function() {
        alert( "The menu has been closed." );
     });
```

Read more on the ones fired by mmenu at http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/custom-events.html

Comment: Thank you I will go and have a look at that now, no idea how I missed that in the documentation :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery hasClass attribute.

```
 $("#mm-0").hasClass("menu-opened");
```

Comment: Yes I know I can do that but my issue is at what point it checks for the class because at the moment it runs through the document jquery and it hasnt got that class, and after Ive opened the menu I dont know how to get it to check again (hope that makes sense)